# Bootstrap Column Allignment

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with allignment of Column. Its not vertically alligned on the browser. I used grid system using bootstrap and tried to fulfill some requirements. Can anyone fix my code or help me fix my code?

```html
![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta][1] charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 

    
    
</head>
<body style= " background-color:grey;">
    


    
     <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
<!--     outer row-->
      <div class="row"> 
          <div class ="col-md-3">
              <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-md-12" style= "border: 2px solid black; background-color:orange; ">
                    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
                    <p> left SIDE BAR  </p>
                  
                  </div>
                  
                  <div class="col-md-12" style= "border: 2px solid black; background-color:orange;">
                    <h2>Heading 2 </h2>
                    <p> LEFT SIDE BAR CONTENT2</p>
                  
                  </div>
              </div>
            
          </div>
          
          <div class ="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1" >
          
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:Yellowgreen;">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut      fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:Salmon;">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              
           </div>
            <div class="col-md-4"style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:Coral;">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
             
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-4" style= "border: 2px solid black; background-color:orange;">
                  <h2>Heading</h2>
                  <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut      fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style= "border: 2px solid black; background-color:purple;">
                  <h2>Heading</h2>
                  <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                  
               </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:lightblue;">
                  <h2>Heading</h2>
                  <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                 
                </div>
               </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:green;">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut      fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:red;">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
                          
                       </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:lavender;">
                          <h2>Heading</h2>
                          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                         
                        </div>
              
                    </div>
          
          </div>
          </div> 
          
      </div>
    </div>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your HTML is not not closing a `div` tag correctly. You've forgot to close the div of first row and closed it somewhere else. Here's your snippet fixed:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta
    ][1] charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body style=" background-color:grey;">


</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <!--     outer row-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:orange; ">
          <h2>Heading 1</h2>
          <p> left SIDE BAR </p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:orange;">
          <h2>Heading 2 </h2>
          <p> LEFT SIDE BAR CONTENT2</p>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:Yellowgreen;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:Salmon;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:Coral;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta
            felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
            massa justo sit amet risus.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:orange;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:purple;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:lightblue;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula
            porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut
            fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:green;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:red;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris
            condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.
            Donec sed odio dui. </p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="border: 2px solid black; background-color:lavender;">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula
            porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut
            fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```